# R Propensity Score Matching with MatchIT

Tags: r, propensity-score-matching

I am new here and I have a question in R. I applied the package matchit to match my propensity score of a glm-output. I created a subset of the original dataset for this because matchit does not allow missings.
My problem is, that the original dataset for further analysis have missings in a lot of different scores. I want to carry out t-tests or welch tests with this metrical variables.

How can i combine the variables of the propensity score matching and the variables of the endpoints (with missings) from the original dataset? When I put the variables together before matching I get a error. But I want to create a dataset with the matched individuals and the endpoint variables. Is match.data the way?

Can anyone help me? I hope my question is understandable:-)

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been fixed in `MatchIt` 4.0.0, which is now on CRAN. You will no longer get an error about missingness as long as neither the covariates nor the treatment has missingness. You can then call `match.data()` on the output object to return the matched dataset, which will be identical to the original dataset but only contain the matched units and will have a few additional columns. The missingness in the original endpoint variable will remain.